# 1-2 Pixel Jitter Animating Horizontal Accordion

Tags: jquery, animation

I am building a custom header for a website that requires some simple animation. The header starts off with 3 divs of the same size, when one of these divs is activated (clicked) the remaining divs shrink while the activated div expands to fill the horizontal space.

The header works fine, but when the divs expand/shrink there tends to be a 1-2 pixel change in the overall horizontal size of the header which makes the header appear to jitter. It can be seen if you focus on the right side of the header when interacting with it.

I've simplified my code down to it's most basic form and added it into a jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/acikib/13/edit

Is there any way to remove the jitter, or a better approach to the implementation that could avoid it?

Comment: Are you using Chrome?  Are you zoomed to something other than 100%?

Comment: @John I am using Chrome, but the same appears to happen in Firefox too. I reset my zoom levels but still no luck. :/ In the jsbin demo above, it only appears to happen for the first click (transition from 3 equally sized boxes to 2 small one one large box), while one my site it happens for all animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is off.  Change your max width to `816` instead of `818`.

Your CSS states that each block is `296`, so `296*3 = 888`.
Your Javascript was telling the large block to be `818` and the small blocks to be `36`.  `818+36*2 = 890`.

So you were increasing the total size of your boxes by 2 pixels, which caused the jagged animation the first time.

http://jsbin.com/acikib/20/edit

Comment: Your bang on, I was 2px off in my math :/ This works like a charm in jsbin, so I will add it as the answer. It improved the jitters on my sites version, but it's still moving around by 1px. I have the feeling it's probably due to the affect of some other CSS. Cheers \o/

Comment: Actually, it's only Chrome that continues to be a pain for my sites version. Firefox/Safari are now fine, I guess I can learn to live with it in chrome. Thanks again.